# How do i get the correct redirect url for my shopify app?

Tags: php, mysql, shopify-app

I am learning how to make Shopify apps right but I am in trouble because even after following every single line of code correctly I can't seem to figure out what I have done wrong.

```
Error - It says theshopifystore.myshopify.com refused to connect
```

everything else is fine i can even store all the info about a store on MySQL but i think the redirect url should be something else can anyone figure out what it is?

Here is the code of all the files that I have made in that process

first - index.php

```
<?php
include_once("inc/mysql_connect.php");
include_once("header.php");?>
```

Second - install.php

```
<?php

// Set variables for our request
$shop = $_GET['shop'];
$api_key = "22xxxxxx151d751c89";
$scopes = "read_orders,write_orders,read_products,write_products";
$redirect_uri = "https://videomap.host/token.php";

// Build install/approval URL to redirect to
$install_url = "https://" . $shop . "/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id=" . $api_key . "&scope=" . $scopes . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($redirect_uri);

// Redirect
header("Location: " . $install_url);

die();?>
```

Third - token.php

```
<?php

// Get our helper functions
require_once("inc/functions.php");
require_once("inc/mysql_connect.php");


// Set variables for our request
$api_key = "x7151d751c89xxxxxxxxxxx";
$shared_secret = "shxxxxxxxxa72837xxxxxx4f";
$params = $_GET; // Retrieve all request parameters
$hmac = $_GET['hmac']; // Retrieve HMAC request parameter

$params = array_diff_key($params, array('hmac' => '')); // Remove hmac from params
ksort($params); // Sort params lexographically

$computed_hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', http_build_query($params), $shared_secret);

// Use hmac data to check that the response is from Shopify or not
if (hash_equals($hmac, $computed_hmac)) {

    // Set variables for our request
    $query = array(
        "client_id" => $api_key, // Your API key
        "client_secret" => $shared_secret, // Your app credentials (secret key)
        "code" => $params['code'] // Grab the access key from the URL
    );

    // Generate access token URL
    $access_token_url = "https://" . $params['shop'] . "/admin/oauth/access_token";

    // Configure curl client and execute request
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $access_token_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($query));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($query));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Store the access token
    $result = json_decode($result, true);
    $access_token = $result['access_token'];

    // Show the access token (don't do this in production!)
    
$sql = "INSERT INTO shop (shop_url, access_token, install_date)
        VALUES ('".$params['shop']."', '".$access_token."', NOW())";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
header('Location: https://'.$params['shop'].'/admin/apps');
    die();
} else {
    echo "Error inserting new record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}


} else {
    // Someone is trying to be shady!
    die('This request is NOT from Shopify!');
}?>
```

Fourth - header.php

```
<?php $shopify = $_GET;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE shop_url='" . $shopify['shop'] . "' LIMIT 1";
$check = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($check) < 1){
    header("Location: install.php?shop=" . $shopify['shop']);
    exit();
}else{
$shop_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check);
$shop_url = $shopify['shop'];

$token = $shop_row['access_token'];


}
?>
```

Fifth - inc/functions.php

```
<?php

function shopify_call($token, $shop, $api_endpoint, $query = array(), $method = 'GET', $request_headers = array()) {
    
    // Build URL
    $url = "https://" . $shop . $api_endpoint;
    if (!is_null($query) && in_array($method, array('GET',  'DELETE'))) $url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($query);

    // Configure cURL
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'My New Shopify App v.1');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);

    // Setup headers
    $request_headers[] = "";
    if (!is_null($token)) $request_headers[] = "X-Shopify-Access-Token: " . $token;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);

    if ($method != 'GET' && in_array($method, array('POST', 'PUT'))) {
        if (is_array($query)) $query = http_build_query($query);
        curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    }
    
    // Send request to Shopify and capture any errors
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $error_number = curl_errno($curl);
    $error_message = curl_error($curl);

    // Close cURL to be nice
    curl_close($curl);

    // Return an error is cURL has a problem
    if ($error_number) {
        return $error_message;
    } else {

        // No error, return Shopify's response by parsing out the body and the headers
        $response = preg_split("/\r\n\r\n|\n\n|\r\r/", $response, 2);

        // Convert headers into an array
        $headers = array();
        $header_data = explode("\n",$response[0]);
        $headers['status'] = $header_data[0]; // Does not contain a key, have to explicitly set
        array_shift($header_data); // Remove status, we've already set it above
        foreach($header_data as $part) {
            $h = explode(":", $part);
            $headers[trim($h[0])] = trim($h[1]);
        }

        // Return headers and Shopify's response
        return array('headers' => $headers, 'response' => $response[1]);

    }
    
}
```

Sixth - inc/mysql_connect.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$username = "xxxxxxx_shopify";
$password ="xxxxxxx1@";
$database = "xxxxxxxopify";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Error" . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
?>
```

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries